# Keras.function Tensor is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I'm getting this error

> ValueError: Tensor Tensor("gradients_3/conv2d_188/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropInput:0", shape=(None, 299, 299, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

with the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, decode_predictions
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing import image   

iv3 = InceptionV3()

x=image.img_to_array(image.load_img("Documents\PythonScripts\libro.jpg", target_size=(299,299)))

x /= 255
x -= 0.5
x *= 2
x = x.reshape([1 , x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2]])

y=iv3.predict(x)
decode_predictions(y)

inp_layer = iv3.layers[0].input
out_layer = iv3.layers[-1].output
target_class = 951
loss = out_layer[0, target_class]

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

grad = K.gradients(loss, inp_layer)[0]

optimize_gradient = K.function([inp_layer, K.learning_phase()],[grad, loss])
```

Comment: Where is the line of code that raised the error? What have you tried yet?

Comment: The error is 'K.function([inp_layer, K.learning_phase()],[grad, loss])'.  'Keras.function' don't recognize `grad=K.gradients(loss, inp_layer)[0]` (Tensor) as a correct paramenter.